# How to receive UDP broadcast packets in Chrome App running on Android

Tags: javascript, cordova, udp, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I can receive broadcast packets without any problems within a windows running chrome app. However, when I take that app and compile using the cordova/crosswalk tools I can't seem to receive any packets. I see all the packets in wireshark. My packet is transmitted from: 172.24.0.42 and broadcasted on 172.24.255.255 (a broadcast on 255.255.255.255 does not work on Android, but it does work on the windows chrome app).

This is my (manifest.json):

```
"sockets":{
        "udp": {
            "bind": "*"
        }
    }, 
    "permissions":["system.network" , "power"],
```

This is my code for my network:

```
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
    socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
    // Setup event handler and bind socket.
    chrome.sockets.udp.onReceive.addListener(onReceive);
    chrome.sockets.udp.bind(socketId, "0.0.0.0", 4213, function(result) {
        if (result < 0) {
            console.log("Error binding socket.");
            return;
        }
    //chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer, '127.0.0.1', 1337, function(sendInfo) {
    //  console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
    //  })
    //chrome.sockets.udp.setBroadcast(socketId, true, function(){})
    });
});
```

This is when I receive the packets:

```
var onReceive = function(info) {
    if (info.socketId !== socketId)
        return;
    chrome.sockets.udp.setPaused(socketId, true, function(){}); // Set socket paused; Essentially blocking
    //console.log();

    ///processing of my packet

    chrome.sockets.udp.setPaused(socketId, false, function(){}); //unpause socket
};
```

Edit: I've been trying my best to understand why I can't get any broadcast packets in the chrome app on Android. Unfortunately, I've ran into a wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setBroadcast` has been added to the library. You can now call `setBroadcast()` to enable broadcast permissions.

> 1.3.0 (Sep 27, 2016)
>
> Adds chrome.udp.setBroadcast()

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

Comment: A link to release notes and/or documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The cordova plugin for chrome-apps-sockets-udp does not enable broadcasts to be received by default.  However with some modification to the plug-in src locally (see below steps) you can enable broadcast messages to be received.  The below info was successfully tested on Android and hope this info is helpful to others who might be struggling to get broadcast messages received.

1) Check if you have installed the cordova plugin for chrome-apps-sockets-udp

```
cordova plugin list
```

if you see this info then the plugin is already installed

```
cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp 1.2.2 "Chrome Apps Sockets UDP API"
```

2) if you don't see the plugin listed then install it:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp
```

3) next, make sure you've added your platform: (ionic example below, phonegap has similar command)

```
ionic platform android
```

4) then build for your app: (ionic example below, phonegap has similar command)

```
ionic build android
```

5) now let's edit the src file in the Android platform.  In a text editor or from your IDE browse to the `<appname>/platforms/android/src/org/chromium` directory and open the `ChromeSocketsUdp.java` file.  Search for this method `void bind(String address, int port)` and after this line `channel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);` add the following line `channel.socket().setBroadcast(true);` and then save the file.

the bind method should now look like the below:

```
  void bind(String address, int port) throws SocketException {
    channel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
    channel.socket().setBroadcast(true);
    channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

    if (multicastSocket != null) {
      bindMulticastSocket();
    }
  }
```

6) Run your application e.g. `ionic run android` and broadcast udp messages should now be received by your Android application.

NOTE: these local changes you've made above will be overridden during the next build.  so if you are happy with your test results you can then modify the plugin src file located at `<appname>/plugins/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp/src/android/ChromeSocketsUdp.java`

here is the gist link to the relevant code sections of the ionic app I wrote for testing the receive of UDP broadcasts on Android [gist.github.com/bfalzarano/e530ca80767a0aea71a145be44943941](https://gist.github.com/bfalzarano/e530ca80767a0aea71a145be44943941)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comprehensive answer. I added the line `channel.socket().setBroadcast(true);` to ChromeSocketsUdp.java in platforms as well as plugins directories. However I am still able to receive only non-broadcasted UDP packets. Could you please share your code?

Comment: @stepan what are you using for your udp client to send broadcast packets? I wrote a node js udp client for sending broadcast packets to make it easier for me to troubleshoot.  also be sure to broadcast to your local subnet as JParrish88 indicates above for Android e.g. if your local subnet is 192.168.0.x/24 then the broadcast address should be 192.168.0.255.  can you up vote my answer if that info was helpful? would a tutorial with the full udp server code and some screenshots be helpful?  if so let me put this together and I can post the link above in my answer.

Comment: I'm using https://packetsender.com/ and it works really good. To be sure that my udp packets are properly broadcasted I also wrote a simple python script: https://gist.github.com/stepanmracek/c66c7d794cc856f1f1a1c88cb74100d6

Comment: @stepan here is the gist link to the relevant code sections of the ionic app I wrote for testing receiving of UDP broadcasts on Android https://gist.github.com/bfalzarano/e530ca80767a0aea71a145be44943941

Comment: Thank you very much. I downloaded your code and create Ionic application from it. However it still does not work. After some investigation I found out that It does not work on my new Android 6.0.1 phone. But when I try the same APK on my old Android 4.4 phone it works flawlessly.
Perhaphs some application permission related to Android 6.0 is missing in application configuration. I will try to find out more detail and keep you informed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the cordova plugin for chrome-sockets-udp?

From the terminal at the root of your project, type in:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp
```